# AngularJS and issue with $localStorage from ngStorage : Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

It looks like my issue is quite simple (i'm probably dumb ;) ) but couldn't point it out.

I found some topics about the same issue I have about localStorage (using ngStorage) on Angular but I can't understand why this syntax doesn't work :

```
 function myCtrl($scope, $http, $resource, $storage, $localStorage) {
   ....
 }

 myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', '$storage', '$localStorage'];
```

Also I defined as well the app in app.js (after installing ngStorage) :

```
 angular.module('onBoardingApp', ['ngStorage', 'ngResource']);
```

this generates this kind if error :

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $storageProvider <- $storage
```

---

some are using the injection via angular.module (I tried it without any success)

```
 angular.module('app', [
   'ngStorage'
 ]).controller('myCtrl', function(
   $scope,
   $localStorage
 ){
  //foo
 });
```

---

### EDIT

I finally get through this issue by using another factory : $store.
Here is the source I used to make it work : http://jsfiddle.net/agrublev/QjVq3/

Comment: Probably there is no `storageProvider` ? http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview

Comment: I know this url but I don't understand what is missing in my demo. I mean, I tested in instanciating the $scope.$storage but without any success.

Comment: Same thing has happened to me... weird thing is it works on one controller but I get this same error on another cntr.

Answer (score 2):

I may be mistaken, but it looks like you are not passing the correct reference to your controller.  The correct usage is just $sessionStorage or $localStorage.  The $storage reference you are using appears to be incorrectly taken from the examples on the GitHub page, and your code is blowing up because there is no actual $storage provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browsers history.  If the controller already has a localStorage variable for that controller and it conflicts with the new localStorage variable you can receive this error.

Answer (score 0):

*Use **ngStorage** in your application for **data persistence**, here whenever you restart your application the data will persists. 
ngStorage stores the data in the same location where HTML5 local storage would store. This is only a wrapper for local storage. 
Whereas, **Local storage** is stored in your browser so as long as you don't clear your data it will be there forever.
In this case there might be some logic problem with resetting server data.*